# Blurry font rendering on non-retina Macs when using NSAttributedString drawing

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, fonts, rendering

I'm using an `NSAttributedString`'s `draw(at:)` function inside of an `NSView` to render some text in a custom font inside my window.
However, the font looks weirdly blurry and "too heavy" when run on a non-retina MacBook (both on the internal display & on an external LCD).
Since I'm able to perfectly reproduce the desired outcome in Sketch on the same machine, I'm assuming this to be an issue with my code.

Here's my code so far:

```
import Cocoa

class StepNameLabel: NSView {
    // Im aware that this is not the intended way of loading Apple's system fonts
    // However, this was the best way I could find to make sure that both Sketch
    // and the app were using the exact same fonts.
    var font = NSFont(name: "SF Pro Text Semibold", size: 22)

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        let text = "Choose your Images"
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .foregroundColor: NSColor.white
        ]
        print(font?.fontName)
        let drawableString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
        frame.size = drawableString.size()
        drawableString.draw(at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot showing the difference between the Sketch-File & the app running on the same display (left: Graphic in Sketch app, right: The output of above code):

[image: Sketch-App comparison.]

The app's code & the Sketch graphic both use Apple's "SF Pro Text" font with a font-weight of "Semibold" at a size of 22 units.

Any help in finding out what's going wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the infamous 'half pixel' problem.  Try:

```
drawableString.draw(at: NSPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
```

There is some information about this [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/411-core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started) (search the page for 'Points and Pixels').